# WKB method as a Semiclassical Approach

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, terminology, definition, semiclassical

A naive question about [WKB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation) approach. It is dubbed to be a "semiclassical" method. What is precisely mean in quantum mechanical context to be "semiclassical"? Wikipedia states that generally semiclassical methods just mean that one part of system is described classically, another quantum mechanically. But what is in WKB precisely the **classical** part?

Isn't it naively thinking purely non-classical since we expand the solution ansatz in $\hbar$? Where sits the precise reason to call it nevetheless "semiclassical" approach?

Can from this example an abstract reason or indication be extracted when an approximation method applied to a quantum mechanical system  should be called to be "semiclassical"?

Addendum/ sidemark: I read (eg [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiclassical_physics) again) that the "One- Loop Approximation" is also regarded in certain sense as semiclassical. (namely the latter mean the breaking of the expansions of entities in powers of coupling constant after terms corresponding to a simple loop wrt Feynman graphs)
Why? After all, what is "classical" component there?

Comment: More here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/417877/226902 (the idea is that $h$ is treated as a small parameter)

Comment: yes sure, but what does it mean here to be "semiclassical"? I' m not sure if calling an approach to be semiclassical is  really equivalent to the possibility to expand a system ( more precisely the action S) in Taylor series in $/hbar$...

Comment: Taylor around $h=0$ is an expansion around the classical limit, hence the name "semiclassical".

Comment: @Quillo: ok, but the Schrödinger equation which we try to solve there is intrinsically " non classical". So say we solve it using WKB and we let then $h \to 0$. Which pure classical result(s) we would  then recover from this? ( if I understand your concern correctly then "semiclassical" means in this approach  that  performing  $h \to 0$ provides something what we know from classical mechanics, but which result is it?)

Answer (score 1):

It is semiclassical since you use a gaussian wavepacket. The central point of such a wavepacket follows exactly the classical equation of motion.

It is then called semiclassical since the central part moves like a classical point object, but you still have a quantistical wave function.

Tell me in the comments if you want me to expand into mathematical details

Comment: thank you, yes, I would be very grateful if you would elaborate the details

Comment: Ok i'll do it as soon as possible

Comment: what I' m not sure about, the Schrödinger equation in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation#Application_to_the_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation which one in WKB wants to approximate is purely  from QM. You said that the center of wave packet follows the classical equation of motion. Yes, but the WKB approximation itself approaches / is designed for a solution of the linked Schrödinger equation, which is purely QMechanical, isn' t? So the crucial point is, where the WKB approach method " involves" the impact of this classical equation of motion of the center of the wavepacket precisely?

Comment: That is the topic of my undergrad thesis, i'll try to make a summary :)